# How can I force Everything search engine to re-index?

Tags: windows-7, search, file-search, everything

I used [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) for searching files on Windows 7. I made many changes in the file system based on the results (deleting and renaming specific files), and I want to check if I covered all the files I have been looking for. Therefore, I need [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) to re-index and give me new results. However, I have not found any option for this on its menus or on its website.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. You looked at the options and didn't find *Force rebuild*? Here is a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yaGK3.png. Doesn't this do exactly what you want?

Comment: Thanks. However, there is no Force rebuild in the options. A screenshot is here: (http://i44.tinypic.com/op1fz6.png). I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: You're right. Update to *Everything 1.3.3.658b Beta* for that option (I had no issues so far with it) or delete the file [`Everything.db`.](http://support.voidtools.com/everything/Database) in your installation folder.

Comment: Hi nixda, thank you for your solution. Why don't you post your helpful comment as an answer? That would certainly direct users with the same question to the right answer. I overlooked your solution and only later found it. I also overlooked the button until I saw your screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but this answer can help.
There is an option to force rebuilding indexes.

1. Launch Everything, then on the menu bar click on Tools -> Options.
2. On the window that open, on the left pane, click on Indexes.
3. On the right pane, click on "Force Rebuild" button.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

Everything listens to the NTFS metadata change and so there is no neeed for a rebuild to get changes shown in the search:

*[**1.5 Does "Everything" monitor file system changes?**](http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php#Does__Everything__monitor_file_system_changes)*

*Yes, "Everything" does monitor file system changes.
Your search windows will reflect changes made to the file system.*

Comment: Unsure why this was downvoted, it seems to be the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, it was apparently my mistake to downvote this correct answer. Must have mis-clicked. Apparently I was consequently taken revenge on later that day with other random downvotes. My bad.